# Adding a day column

Tags: python, pandas, date

Currently I have a csv file consisting of dates. Using python is there a way to add in a new column to display which day (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.) the specific date in the row is? For example, if the date shows 8 Sep 2018 the respective day should be Sat in the new column. [First 15 rows of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih8wM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Considered dataframe

```
                Date
546451991   2018-07-31 00:00:00
546451991   2018-08-02 00:00:00
5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00
5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00
5441440119  2018-08-14 00:00:00
5344265358  2018-07-13 00:00:00
5344265358  2018-07-15 00:00:00
5441438884  2018-07-19 00:00:00
```

extracting the day of dataframe

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.day_name()
df
```

Out:

```
                Date              day
546451991   2018-07-31 00:00:00 Tuesday
546451991   2018-08-02 00:00:00 Thursday
5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00 Monday
5441440119  2018-08-13 00:00:00 Monday
5441440119  2018-08-14 00:00:00 Tuesday
5344265358  2018-07-13 00:00:00 Friday
5344265358  2018-07-15 00:00:00 Sunday
5441438884  2018-07-19 00:00:00 Thursday
```

Please go through the Pandas documentation for more information about pandas function.

[Pandas Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231987/8208006)